# TCS javascript: technical written question

Tags: javascript

I don't know what is the output of this and how the flows go to solve it

```js
console.log(60+"20" - 20*20);
```

Answer (score 1):

JS implicitly converts
`number + string = string`

Therefore, `60+"20" = "60"+"20" = "6020"`

```js
let a = "60"+20;
console.log(a, typeof a)
```

---

Then, JS implicitly converts
`string - number = number`

Therefore,  `"6020" - 20*20 = "6020" - 400 = 6020-400 = 5620`

```js
let a = "6020" - 20*20;
console.log(a, typeof a)
```

**Note: You can check `datatype` as well of each `result` for clarity of each result after conversion**

Answer (score 0):

Well it gets processed as follows:

```
60+"20" becomes 6020
20*20 = 400
6020-400 = 5620
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output : 5620

20*20 = 400 ->1st
60+'20' = 6020 -> 2nd
6020 - 400 = 5620 -> 3rd
```